# C++ function reads a file with the name 1234.4678.npy as 1234,4678.npy

Tags: c++, numpy, format

I'm trying to read .npy files with cnpy library (C++ library) using npy_load function of cnpy. All the file names are named with a format like the following:
1234.4567.npy.
However, npy_load function read the file replacing the first dot with comma and the algorithms search files with the name:
1234,4567.npy. As a result, it raises the following error:
npy_load: Unable to open file 1234,4567.npy

The code that uses the npy_load is the following:

```
void getdescriptor(string filename,cv::Mat & descriptor,int nkeypoints){
    cnpy::NpyArray arr = cnpy::npy_load(filename);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nkeypoints ; i ++){
        float* pdata= descriptor.ptr<float>(i);
        for(int j = 0 ; j < 256 ; j ++ ){
            float temp = arr.data<float>()[i *256 + j];
            pdata[j]= temp;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: What's your locale?

Comment: Have you verified that `filename`
 is what you expect in the code before calling `npy_load`?

Comment: are you sure npy_load is doing this?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. @molbdnilo, I have verified that filename is what I expect. I added a cout statement in order to see what are the actual names that npy_load read. The weird thing is that the first two files are printed with the right way (with dot) while the next one is printed with comma before the npy_load, while after that, the code raises the error that referred above. I removed that file and the problem remained the same with the next file.

Comment: From your description, it sounds like the filenames are actually *not* what you expect, and it's not `npy_load` that messes with them. Where do you get the filenames from?

Comment: @molbdnilo yes, npy_load works fine. Finally, I solved the problem, I had to change the variable LC_NUMERIC in the locale settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after more research based on the comments above, I solved the problem. The cnpy library and its npy_load function works fine. The issue raised because of the variable LC_NUMERIC of locale settings. All I had to do is to replace the value of this variable, with "en_US.UTF-8":

```
echo 'export LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"' >>~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

And the problem solved.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this; it's a sign that your method for acquiring or generating the filenames is flawed.